# Add a new line after a matched pattern in Notepad++

Tags: regex, pattern-matching, notepad++, line, break

I have a csv-file, now i need to bring it in another form.

I want to have a line break \r\n after a specific pattern.

All patterns look like this:

```
true or false; int number between 0 and 100; decimal number with two or three digits after the point; true or false;
```

For example:

```
false;2;23.987;false;
true;0;8.37;false;
false;8;166.987;false;
```

and after the last semicolon, i want to have a line break. I am using notepad++.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Try `\b(?:true|false);\d+;\d+\.\d+;(?:true|false);` and replace with `$0\r\n`

Comment: You need to give more information on how you are trying to implement your solution. Are you using a script or code etc.

Comment: Thank you Wiktor, this worked! Thank you so much!

Comment: Well, the question is very clear to me, and, using Forex terminology, I could not help "scalping" it :). Answer is posted below.

Comment: If all the file is in one line with this format (groups of 4 fields), you don't need to describe the fields and you can use `(?:[^;]*;){4}\K` and replace with `\r\n`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
\b(?:true|false);\d+;\d+\.\d+;(?:true|false);
```

or a more precise acc. to your specs:

```
\b(?:true|false);(?:\d{1,2}|100);\d+\.\d{2,3};(?:true|false);
```

and replace with `$0\r\n`.

**Details**:

- `\b` - word boundary
- `(?:true|false)` - a non-capturing group matching either `true` or `false`
- `;` - a literal `;`
- `(?:\d{1,2}|100)` - either any 1 or 2 digits or `100`
- `;` - a semi-colon
- `\d+\.\d{2,3}` - 1+ digits, a literal `.` and then 2 or 3 digits
- `;` - a `;`
- `(?:true|false)` - again either `true` or `false`
- `;` - finally, the last semi-colon.

[image]